# Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed?Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angular-services

I have created notification service globally for the application, while sending the db call, capturing the error code in interceptors and show alert.

how to avoid the duplicated Error mesage in angular notication service.
**Interceptor code**

```
 var interceptor = function ($q, alerts, $rootScope, $timeout, $location, alertsManager) {

                   return {
                       request: function (config) {
                           console.log(config);
                           return config;
                       },
                       response: function (response) {
                           var deferred = $q.defer();
                           //$rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
                           //$scope.alerts.push({ msg: "Request done !" });
                           return response || $q.when(response);
                      },
                       responseError: function (rejection) {
                           if (rejection.status == 500)
                           {

                               var deferred = $q.defer();                         
                               $rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');

                               return $q.reject(rejection);
                           }

                           console.log(rejection.status);
                           return $q.reject(rejection);
                       }
                   }
               };

            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
```

Inside the controller calling the server call response.

```
 LoginService.AfterLogin(UserName, Password)).then(function (response) {

        },function (status) {

                        if (status === 500) {

                          alert("200");

                            $rootScope.$on("loginRequired", function (e) {                           

                             alertsManager.addAlert('Technical Error Occurred.Please contact the System Administrator for the further support!!', 'alert-success');
                            });

                        }

                    });
```

factory alert service

```
App.factory('alertsManager', function () {
    return {
        alerts: {},
        addAlert: function (message, type) {
            this.alerts[type] = this.alerts[type] || [];
            this.alerts[type].push(message);
        },
        clearAlerts: function () {
            for (var x in this.alerts) {
                delete this.alerts[x];
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Method1:

```
<div ng-controller="AlertsController">        
            <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in alerts" class=" alert {{key}}" id="alert-notify">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <div ng-repeat="msg in val">{{msg}}</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

[image]
Method1:
Method2:
When i am using track by $index , getting duplicated.

```
<div ng-controller="AlertsController">        
            <div ng-repeat="(key,val) in alerts track by $index" class=" alert {{key}}" id="alert-notify">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <div ng-repeat="msg in val track by $index">{{msg}}</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you tagging it as angular2?

Comment: Isn't the last example correct? Can you show the actual data so we know what it is supposed to look like?

Comment: i am not getting u what you saying ,2 times error response triggered and show  the duplicate error.

Comment: Your interceptor getting called multiple times resulting in multiple error messages has nothing to do with `track by`.

Comment: Are you only expecting one error message? Are you sure only one call is made?

Comment: @ tasseKATT 3 calls triggered thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try use  msg (or msg.someKey when it is an object) rather then $index

```
<div ng-repeat="msg in val track by msg">{{msg}}</div>
```

but msg need to be not identical. try this

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,val) in alerts track by key" class=" alert {{key}}" id="alert-notify">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <div ng-repeat="msg in val track by $index">{{msg}}</div>
            </div>
```

$index fits good in second repeater

Comment: if i given like that gets duplicated the message as shown in screenshot above,because error function triggered 3 times.